# Is it safe to use Free instead of Release for modal forms in Delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi, memory-management, modal-dialog

The Delphi online help says that Release should be used to remove a form from memory. However, in many examples for modal forms I have seen this construct:

```
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(nil);
try
  MyForm.ShowModal;
finally
  MyForm.Free;
end;
```

Is Free a safe way to destroy a modal form? As I can see in the source for ShowModal, Application.HandleMessage will be called until the ModalResult is not 0. Is this the reason why Free can not interfere with pending windows messages?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274523/form-release-nil

Comment: Note: there is a Delphi bug related to closing secondary Delphi forms. It will crash your application: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33140

Comment: Everybody say it is free to use Free, but nobody managed to explain why. What if the form was destroyed via "Action:= caFree" ? The answer is because CloseModal calls Release if Action is set to caFree.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to use `Free` after a `ShowModal` call.

The cases where you need to use `Release` are times when you're in the middle of an event handler (eg, `OnClick`), where further processing after the event will have to access the form.  In that case, calling `Release` instead posts a `CM_RELEASE` message which doesn't free the event until the event handler is done and control has returned to the message pump (`ProcessMessages`/`Application.Run`).  `ShowModal` doesn't return until the event handler is finished and control makes it back up the stack, so calling `Free` afterwards is effectively the same place where the `CM_RELEASE` message would be processed otherwise.

Comment: And be careful not to have any Application.ProcessMessages calls!

Comment: @GerryColl Why? And where exactly?

Comment: @Bozzy If you use `Release` and then call `Application.ProcessMessages` the `WM_RELEASE` message will be processed and the form will be freed.  Gerry's concern is if you're using Release to postpone the destruction and then accidentally freeing the form before you're actually done with it.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you need to clarify that when you say "there are times when you're in the middle of an event handler" you are referring exclusively to event handlers that are in the form that you want to release.

Comment: You are explaining what is happening during Release. That's fine, the explanation is good. But you don't explain why it is safe to use Free (which is the actual question). The answer is because CloseModal calls Release if Action is set to caFree.

Comment: @IceCold In the example provided it's safe to use Free because ShowModal has returned so the dialog is no longer visible and not in the middle of processing any messages.  There's nothing higher on the stack that has references to it.  That means you can call Free and immediately deallocate the memory without an outer call accessing the freed memory.  That has nothing to do with CloseModal.  CloseModal would have already run with Action set to caNone.

Comment: "ShowModal has returned" - What if that form has Action = caFree?

Answer (score 8):

It depends. `Free`ing the form doesn't call the event handlers that `Release` does, and any messages that might have been posted to the form and are queued will not be processed. So while, in many and possibly most cases calling `Free` (or `FreeAndNil`) will work fine, it may lead to some highly weird behaviour for seemingly random reasons.

The alternative that I'd suggest is in the OnClose event set the Action to caFree, like this:

```
procedure FormClose(Sender : TObject; Action : TCloseAction)
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

You can then write code like this:

```
TMyForm.Create(nil).ShowModal;
```

And you don't need to free the form specifically, since it'll free itself when it's done.

Comment: I like the creativity this shows, but I would never use it as the code shown in the question is just the idiomatic way to do it - with your code I would always wonder if the form is freed correctly when stumbling over this after some months.

Comment: Meh, whatever you feel is best. However, this does encapsulate the functionality of the form entirely and reduces your chance for forgetting to free it.

Comment: Setting action to caFree simply calls Release. You have to be careful if you want to access properties of the form after showmodal, in case something (broken?) calls ProcessMessages

Comment: The CM_Release method simply calls Free()  Why do you say freeing the form doesn't call the event handlers that Release does?

Comment: @mghie @ Tim - A comment like "Action = caFree" at the end of the ShowModal line will be sufficient to indicate what happens with the form.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely, and you can also use the FreeAndNil routine.  The FreeAndNil routine will only free the object if it is not already nil, and also set it to nil after the free.  If you call free directly on an object which has already been freed, you get an Access Violation.

```
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(nil); 
try 
  MyForm.ShowModal; 
finally 
  FreeAndNil(MyForm); 
end;
```

Comment: Small nitpick: Free will also only free the object if it is not already nil, the second part is the important one.

Comment: If MyForm is a local variable, using FreeAndNil() is certainly overkill. MyForm.Free is sufficient, in fact MyForm.Destroy would work just as well.

Comment: +for Allen - Overuse of FreeAndNil can hide errors that would have been picked up by the compiler - it won't complain if the object may not have been initialised (usually conditional creation).
This also doesn't answer the question (YES IT IS OK).

Comment: Is there any danger here of Free being called on an object that has already been freed? If not, then it's not "far" better to use FreeAndNil. If there is danger, then FreeAndNil won't actually help in this case anyway. (Remember, you free objects, not a variables. MyForm is a variable, not an object.)

Comment: My assumption here was that MyForm was the "global" variable created by the editor when the unit was first created.  I agree with Allen IF the variable is completely local then .free is sufficient since the variable falls out of scope.

Comment: @GerryColl- I don't understand when you're saying that FreeAndNil can hide errors. Can you give a concrete example? A variable that went through FreeAndNil, is always in a defined state (NIL).