# Dynamically created TPopup menu does not call the OnClick event handlers of its items in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

I want to test something and created a simple dynamic popup menu example. I had to realize that the popup menu appears normally but it does not call the onClick event handler. I tried to rename everything to avoid the name collisions, made the event handler virtual, public, but it did not solve the problem. I have restarted the IDE (I think this code should work fine) but it is the same. The compiler options are the new project defaults. The statically created (placed on the form) popupmenu works fine, just the dynamiically created one take a rest.
Which property of the dynamic menu should I fill up with some value? Somebody explain the reason, please!

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    staticPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure addMenuItem( popupmenu_ : TPopupMenu; caption_ : string; tag_ : integer; onClick_ : TNotifyEvent );
    procedure onmenuitemclick1( sender_ : TObject );
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.addMenuItem( popupmenu_ : TPopupMenu; caption_ : string; tag_ : integer; onClick_ : TNotifyEvent );
var
  menuitem1 : tmenuitem;
begin
  menuitem1 := tmenuitem.create( popupmenu_ );
  menuitem1.caption := caption_;
  menuitem1.Tag := tag_;
  menuitem1.onclick := onclick_;
  popupmenu_.items.add( menuitem1 );
end;

procedure TForm1.onmenuitemclick1( sender_ : TObject );
var
  id : integer;
begin
  id := tmenuitem( sender_ ).Tag;
  showmessage( 'menuitem.onclick called! (' + intToStr( id ) + ')' );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dynamicPopupMenu : tpopupmenu;
begin
  dynamicPopupMenu := tpopupmenu.create( self );
  try
    addMenuItem( dynamicPopupMenu, 'aaa', 1, onmenuitemclick1 );
    addMenuItem( dynamicPopupMenu, 'bbb', 2, onmenuitemclick1 );
    dynamicPopupMenu.popup( 500, 500 );
  finally
    dynamicPopupMenu.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  staticPopupMenu.items.Clear;
  addMenuItem( staticPopupMenu, 'aaa', 1, onmenuitemclick1 );
  addMenuItem( staticPopupMenu, 'bbb', 2, onmenuitemclick1 );
  staticPopupMenu.popup( 500, 500 );
end;

end.
```

The dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 339
  Top = 270
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 601
  ClientWidth = 854
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 96
    Top = 128
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 177
    Top = 128
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button2'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object staticPopupMenu: TPopupMenu
    Left = 280
    Top = 128
  end
end
```

Comment: @MartynA It is strange, because I created a new project, etc and the result is the same. Maybe it is an environment dependent issue. Which IDE do you tested it with?

Comment: @MartynA Obviously I wouldn't create this question if it works fine to me (and sure for other ones)

Comment: @MartynA The issue is live to me with D 10.2 as well. So there should be something in the environment.

Comment: @MartynA And with D7 as well. Are you sure you try the dynamic generated menu handler? (onButton1Click) Button2 works fine to me. This is the base for the comparison.

Comment: I can confirm that the meu item click do not work, and the reson is that you `Free` the menu immediately after you show it. Free the menu in the OnClick handler and it will work.

Comment: You are right, I spoke too soon. But anyway, the destructor is called before the item onclick. I will try to figure out something.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sorry, I deleted my previous comment because I almost exceed the edition time limit.  it seems so the onclick handler called by `postmessage`. the call of free on the popup called first as Tom Brunberg said. If I call an application.processMessages before free, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @TomBrunberg, I should have passed by the moment I saw the call to `Free`.

Comment: @MartynA In this case it seems to me you don't test the code I posted?

Comment: Don't rush into `Application.ProcessMessages()`. After all you are already in a button click, menu handler and on the way to a item click. You may get into deeper hole with AP

Comment: @TomBrunberg I do not quite understand what you wrote. What is your recommendition to solve the problem?

Comment: Calling AP while you are in a chain of event handlers may present re-entrancy problems, because all messages in the que are fired. But I'm a little busy now, I'll check back later if I get to think of a better solution.

Comment: @TomBrunberg OK: Thanks in advance. :) What does AP stand for?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Maybe I should create garbage collector (put popupmenu into it instead of calling the free) and free the collected items up on idle time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating your `dynamicPopupMenu` with the current `TForm1` instance
as `Owner`, I'm not really sure you need all the rigmarole of your garbage collector,
as the `TForm1` instance will destroy it anyway when it itself is destroyed.

Try this:

1. Set a breakpoint on `TComponent.Destroy` in Classes.Pas and a watch on `Tag`.
2. Change your `Button1Click` as shown below, disable your garbage collector,
   compile, run and observe.

{code}

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dynamicPopupMenu : tpopupmenu;
  AForm : TForm;
begin
  AForm := TForm.Create(Nil);
  dynamicPopupMenu := tpopupmenu.create(AForm);
  try
    dynamicPOpUpMenu.Tag := 666;
    addMenuItem( dynamicPopupMenu, 'aaa', 1, onmenuitemclick1 );
    addMenuItem( dynamicPopupMenu, 'bbb', 2, onmenuitemclick1 );
    dynamicPopupMenu.popup( 600, 600 );
  finally
    AForm.Release;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Me too, like I said, try it for fun.  The whole "dynamic menu" thing seems a bit bogus to me, so I'm not surprised it's all a bit messy.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Please see my update, which imo dispenses with the need for artifices, at the minor expense of creating a dummy owner for the PopUpMenu.  Imo, the OP's whole approach is wrong - trying to make a TComponent outlive its scope - and creates the problem he then has to fudge his way around.

Comment: It is well-founded to release the instances, because the release on TForm1 destroy is too late. The user can call the menu in countless times in the program execution duration. However the TForm.release solution is very specious and effective. I think it uses a built in garbage collection in the background.

Comment: I created this problem to myself because the popup creater wont be the form itself in the final architect, but a controller PODO (pure old delphi object). It was just a trial,  simplified case. And i dont want to pass throgh the popupmenu in the stack. The controller creares it, because its content widely depends on the current user operation.

Comment: @User007:  "specious" and "effective" mean contradictory things, so I'm not really sure what you are saying.  In any case, if you trace my code, you'll find that each time `Button1Click` is invoked, `dynamicPopupMenu` is destroyed immediate afterwards - there is no "garbage collector` involved, just the VCL's normal message-handling - see the accepted answer to this q for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916843/is-it-safe-to-use-free-instead-of-release-for-modal-forms-in-delphi

Comment: yes. this destroy it right after that. but if you reread my comment, it says : TForm1.Free. The first idea right at the beginning of your answer.

Comment: I thought you were joking, Martyn? I would never create a temporary form just to be able to delay the destruction of something. A timer would do just as well with much, much less overhead.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Much, much? What less overhead do you have in mind, time, memory or what?

Comment: Yes, anything and everything measurable

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the issue. A user defined message should do just fine with very little overhead. So...

Define a Windows message:

```
const
  WM_FREE_MY_DYNAMENU = WM_USER + 0;
```

Move the `dynamicPopupMenu` variable to the form and define a handler for the message:

```
TForm12 = class(TForm)
...
protected
  dynamicPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
  procedure FreeMyDynaMenu(var Message: TMessage); message WM_FREE_MY_DYNAMENU;
```

Implement it:

```
procedure TForm12.FreeMyDynaMenu(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  dynamicPopupMenu.Free;
end;
```

Finally in the Button1Click replace the call to `Free` with posting the message:

```
finally
//  dynamicPopupMenu.Free;
  PostMessage(self.Handle, WM_FREE_MY_DYNAMENU, 0, 0);
```

You should also NOT assign the form as the owner when you create the menu:

```
dynamicPopupMenu := tpopupmenu.create( nil ); // self replaced with nil
```

And an even more simple alternative to the above (although not to my liking) would be to use a `TTimer` to delay the call to `Free`.

Comment: In my posted environment it is would be a working solution (is it sure the posted messages processed in the dispatch order?) However in my final architecture the popup creator will be a PODO (plail old delphi object).  And those unable to gandle events.

Comment: The posted messages are processed in order, unless ... somebody peeks and pokes in the message queue, but why would you do that?. I believe I have answered your question. If you did not describe your actual environment correctly, you can only blame yourself. Did I just waste my time?

Comment: no. i wrote this is a working solution. i was just a question about the processing order of the posted messages. the java JMS use priorities, etc. but if this always process them in a sequential order, then i accept your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately i can just accept one solution and MartynA's solution is usable in a wider range.

Comment: @User007 You are absolutely free to accept the answer that suits you best. Additionally you can upvote, as you have > 15 reps,  any or all answers you think are useful, and downvote, as you have > 125 reps, any answers that you think are not useful.